# EF Core 7.0 - Integrated Security Not Working

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have upgraded my API to use .NET 7.0, I am aware of the breaking changes of the upgrade.

I added the `Encrypt=False;` to my connection string, and then got

> Login failed for user '.'

I then added `Integrated Security=True` to the connection string, and then got the following message again:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

Do I have to use EF Core 7.0 with a SQL authentication login?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use the `TrustServerCertificate = True` option in order to get this to work, seeing as you're most probably using a self-signed certificate on the SQL server.

Add that to your connection string, and things should start working.

Comment: I have that in my connection string:
"DB": "Server=Server;Database=DB;TrustServerCertificate=True;"

I then get this error:
"Login failed for user ''.",

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server logs for the actual authentication error, @John . Perhaps there are 2 parts to this; the cert and wrong credentials.

Comment: @John Are you including `IntegratedSecurity=True` in the connection string as well?

Comment: @akseli here is my connection string:
Server=server\\sql2019;Database=DB_Test;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Integrated Security=True

And then I get A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

Comment: @Larnu I have checked the logs.

As soon as I specify the correct credentials I get this error:
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

Comment: *"I have checked the logs"* And what did they say when you got *"Login failed for user"* in the application, @John ?

Comment: @Larnu that only happens when I do not specify the SQL Authentication credentials.

I need to run this with Windows Auth - which is not working